# Problem with sprite sheet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiimage

The code below shows how I'm cutting my sprites, but the memory usage grows constantly. How can I fix?

```
CGImageRef imgRef = [imgSprite CGImage];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgRef, CGRectMake(column*width, line, width, height))]];
CGImageRelease(imgRef);
```

This code is called by the NSTimer in an interval of 0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven’t posted the declaration of `imgSprite`, I’ll assume that its class follows Cocoa naming conventions.

In:

```
CGImageRef imgRef = [imgSprite CGImage];
```

that method (a non-NARC<sup>1</sup> method) returns an object that you **do not** own, hence you **should not** release it.

In:

```
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgRef, CGRectMake(column*width, line, width, height))]];
```

the argument is the expression:

```
CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgRef, CGRectMake(column*width, line, width, height))
```

`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` (a function whose name follows the Create Rule<sup>2</sup>) returns an image that you **do** own, hence you **should** release it, which you don’t.

In:

```
CGImageRelease(imgRef);
```

you’re releasing an image that you **do not** own, so you **should not** release it.

You have two problems: you’re (potentially over)releasing `imgRef` and you’re leaking the image returned by `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()`.

You should do the following instead:

```
// you do not own imgRef, hence you shouldn’t release it
CGImageRef imgRef = [imgSprite CGImage];

// use a variable for the return value of CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()
// because you own the return value, hence you should release it later
CGImageRef imgInRect = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgRef, CGRectMake(column*width, line, width, height));

[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgInRect]];

CGImageRelease(imgInRect);
```

You might want to read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html).

<sup>1</sup>NARC = new, alloc, retain, copy

<sup>2</sup>The [Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) states that if you call a function whose name contains Create or Copy then you own the return value, hence you should release it when you don’t need it any longer.